Алгоритм проверки свободного места в таблице с учетом перемещения

На скрине представлен веб интерфейс. При изменении элементов нижнего раздела должна происходить проверка, что такой элемент вместиться и на первой строке. Тут к примеру если попытаться растянуть красный элемент во второй, то его можно вместить на первой если поменять местами с фиолетовым и т.д. Прошу помощи разобраться в том, как проверить то, что элемент с известными параметрами поместиться с учетом того, что другие элементы можно двигать вверх или вниз. Количество рядом в данном случае 5.
На ум приходил алгоритм сборки рюкзака, но не придумал как его применить в данном случае

Также необходимо понять, что именно нужно подвинуть в первой строке, чтобы вместился элемент, если это возможно
